# Firebasedatabase on days with no user input

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an Android app that will require user to input data everyday and I am using Firebase database to store those data, however on days that user did not input a data I want a new node to be created automatically in Firebase database so that I can use it to list and plot as I will need the date and a default value on those days. How can I create a node on Firebase database when date changes when there is no user input on that day?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in a very simple way, by adding `default` values to your properties. So assuming you have a database structure that looks like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- dateNode
          |
          --- propertyOne: null
```

You need to know that because there is no data that is assigned to the `propertyOne` field, the following refence will not even exist at all:

```
Firebase-root -> yourNode -> propertyOne //Will not appear in the database
```

If your property is of type String, then add a default value that looks like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- dateNode
          |
          --- propertyOne: ""
```

If you propertyOne is of type number, then add a default value that looks like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- dateNode
          |
          --- propertyOne: -1
```